# Mixed model specification with lmer: intra and inter rater variability

Tags: anova, mixed-model

I'm going through some trouble to understand how to translate my experimental design into a mixed model. The idea is to compare the sources of variance in a method of measurement.

The design is as follows: we took **3 samples**, each sample went through **3 different treatments** (not the same 3 for each sample - this is a biological problem, the treatment is a staining procedure necessary for the measure, not an experimental intervention), then each one of **3 raters** took **3 measures** of each sample/treatment combination to a total of 81 measures.

Sample data would look like this:

`sample     treatment      rater        rep      measure
 1          1              Person A     1        200
 2          1              Person B     1        210
 3          1              Person C     1        190
 1          2              Person A     1        230 
 2          2              Person B     1        235
 3          2              Person C     1        210
 1          3              Person A     1        250
 2          3              Person B     1        270
 3          3              Person C     1        260
 1          1              Person A     2        180
 2          1              Person B     2        220
 3          1              Person C     2        200
 1          2              Person A     2        230 
 2          2              Person B     2        245
 3          2              Person C     2        220
 1          3              Person A     2        240
 2          3              Person B     2        275
 3          3              Person C     2        280
...`

The thing is then how to specify and interpret the model for *lmer* to be able to tell something about where the variability comes from (the treatments, the samples, inter-rater or intra-rater). More fundamentally, is a mixed model a good way to answer this question about the sources of variability? What's the difference between this an analysis of variance?

I guess I'm looking for something like these, but I'm not sure I got the way of model specification (nor how to interpret the model when it has many interactions):

```
measure ~ (1|sample/treatment) + rater
measure ~ (1|sample) + (1|treatment) + rater
```

Regarding interpretation, say I've run the second model above and get this output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: PercNeurons ~ (1 | sample) + (1 | treatment) + rater
   Data: sample.data
REML criterion at convergence: 438.5817
Random effects:
 Groups       Name          Std.Dev.
 sample       (Intercept)   0.3377  
 treatment    (Intercept)   1.0087  
 Residual                   3.7154  
Number of obs: 81, groups:  sample, 3; treatment, 3
Fixed Effects:
     (Intercept)  raterPersonB    raterPersonC  
          25.379          1.604          2.477
```

Can I interpret this output as follows:

1. inter-rater reliability (between each pair) being 1.604 and 2.477
2. variability due to different treatments is smaller than inter-rater, 1.0087
3. variability in the samples is even smaller, 0.3377
4. the residual variance is the intra-rater variability plus a random error

In that case, could I specify the model differently as to be able to separate the intra-rater variability from the random error?

Let me know if can clarify anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may just be the way you've presented your simulated data set, but it seems that always Person A = sample 1, Person B = sample 2, Person = sample 3 and so in their current presentation they shouldn't be in the same model.

Maybe you want to asses the within-rater repeatability, and you should check out Nakagawa & Schielzeth (2010) Repeatability for Gaussian and non-Gaussian data: a practical guide for biologists
10.1111/j.1469-185X.2010.00141.x
and associated package "rptR" 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rptR/vignettes/rptR.html

You might also want to check out the ranef() function, using your example which will show you the variance in your model attributable to each of the levels of a random factor

```
mod1<- lmer(PercNeurons ~ (1 | sample) + (1 | treatment) + rater, data=sample.data)

ranef(mod1)
```

Hope that gives you a starting point.